# Subscript out of range IF ISERROR question

Tags: excel, vba

This is driving me mad. I've looked for an answer to this problem, but can't find an exact match. The line:

```
If IsError(Sheets(this_year)) Then GoTo Line99
```

is designed to establish if the sheet `6th April YYYY` exists. If I use 2019 (which does exist), the following code runs fine. However if I use 2020 (which DOESN't exist) gives me

> Error code 9, Subscript out of range.

```
    Dim this_year As String
    this_year = "6th April 2020"
    Windows("Retirement Planning - Copy.xlsx").Activate
    If IsError(Sheets(this_year)) Then GoTo Line99
    Windows("Savings Details - Copy.xlsm").Activate
    MsgBox ("Congratulation")
    GoTo Line100
    Line99:
    MsgBox ("This year does not exist")
    Line100:
End Sub
```

I thought "If IsError" was supposed to "trap" an error and do something, but I'm obviously doing something "blindingly obvious" incorrectly!!

Comment: All `IsError` does is check to see if a `Variant` has a type of `Error`. It is not an error handler.

Comment: You should also ditch the `On Error GoTo Line99` and nest this inside your `IF` statement. The `Else` statement will handle the event that there isn't an error (once you trap for the correct error as mentioned in above comments)

Comment: What are you trying to check? If that workbook has a sheet called `6th April 2020`? If the active sheet has that name, etc.?

Comment: Style commentary: I prefer not to depend on error handling for this sort of thing. It's a bit slower, but loop through your worksheets and compare with the names. If you don't find it, manage the result. If you do, then you have the worksheet needed. I dislike code that jumps around based on errors.

Comment: Use the SheetExists function found here:[Function to test if excel sheet exists](http://codevba.com/excel/sheet_exists.htm#.W-RkT9VKjcc).  Use `IsError()` when checking for WorksheetFunction errors [MS Excel: How to use the ISERROR Function (WS, VBA)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php)

Comment: Added a solution using `IsError` as one line condition, thus avoiding as well error handling as looping through the worksheets collection :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it.

```
Dim thisYear As String
Dim currSheet as Worksheet
Dim found as Boolean

thisYear = "6th April 2020"

Windows("Retirement Planning - Copy.xlsx").Activate

For Each currSheet in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If currSheet.Name = thisYear Then
         found = True
         Exit For
    End If
Next

If found Then
    MsgBox ("Congratulations! " & currSheet.Name & " Found!")
Else
    MsgBox ("The sheet named " & thisYear & " does not exist")
End If
```

Comment: (OP) Notice how this method does not use `On Error GoTo Line99`. You can build these statements inside your `IF` statement. Now your code follows a straight line and is easy to follow, understand, and debug. +1

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub ErrorKatcher()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As String

    s = "whatever"
    On Error GoTo gotcha
        Set ws = Sheets(s)
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "NO ERROR"
    Exit Sub
gotcha:
    MsgBox "an error occurred"
End Sub
```

Comment: To answer BruceWayne, yes, I am trying to establish if the workbook has a sheet of that name, or not? To answer a couple of others I'm trying to use IsError NOT OnError (which I've been advised to stay away from!). I rather like stonegiants answer as it appears to be concise and (more importantly) easy to follow. Thank you all for your comments. If anyone has any better suggestion - I'm all ears (so to speak!)

Comment: @user2627814 `On Error Goto Label` is perfectly fine, and there isn't a reason to avoid it for dealing with unanticipated exceptions. `On Error Resume Next` is what should generally be avoided (although it has a narrow set of legitimate use cases as well). That said, I have to agree with StoneGiant that error handling should not be used for program flow control when it *can* be avoided.

Comment: @user2627814  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Your help and assistance is truly appreciated. I've been stumped as to what I was doing wrong for hours and "desperation" finally drove me to ask for help. I'm self taught, and since I don't know much about VBA, I'm a lousy teacher. I've "sort of" migrated from Excel Macros, which i thought were pretty astounding, and I found there wasn't much I couldn't do with them. But hey, to "stand still" is to travel backwards these days. Thanks again to you all.

Answer (score 1):

**Avoiding as well loop and error handling**

You can use `IsError` in a one liner, but referring to any existant cell (e.g. `A1`):

```
Sub CheckWS()
Dim thisYear$: thisYear = "6th April 2020"
Windows("Retirement Planning - Copy.xlsx").Activate

If Not IsError(Application.Evaluate("'" & thisYear & "'!A1")) Then
    MsgBox ("Congratulations! '" & thisYear & "' Found!")
Else
    MsgBox ("The sheet named '" & thisYear & "' does not exist")
End If
End Sub
```